# can't re-create PouchDB database with same name

Tags: pouchdb

I want to repeatedly create and delete a PouchDB database with the same name ('Test') during my unit tests. But if I add at least one document to the database before deleting it, then the next time I try to create it I get the error:

"Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'objectStore' on 'IDBTransaction': The specified object store was not found."

This happens at pouchdb.js:1950:

```
var docStore = transaction.objectStore(DOC_STORE);  // PouchDB 3.0.6
```

Then if I look at IndexedDB, the DB does exist but only with the following info:

```
Security origin:http://localhost:8000
Name:_pouch_Test
Integer Version:1
String Version:
```

Then if I try to delete this DB, Angular throws a 'CustomPouchError', which I haven't traced through.

Here are the relevant code snippets from my app:

```
var db = new PouchDB(dbName, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
        $log.info('Database \'' + dbName + '\' opened');  // Happens when I first create 'Test'
    } else {
        $log.info('Database \'' + dbName + '\' failed to open');  // Happens when I try to re-create 'Test'
    }
});

db.destroy(function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
        $log.error(err);
    } else {
        $log.info("Database destroyed");  // Happens when I delete 'Test'
    }
});
```

But if I delete the database before adding any documents to it, it disappears from IndexedDB and then I can create it again.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround. After destroy, create a new PouchDB object in the "then" function. It works fine next time you use it.
Eg.

```
 var db = new PouchDB('Xyz');

 db.destroy().then(function (response) {
        db = new PouchDB('Xyz');
    });
```

Comment: It's weird but it works - if new PouchDB assigned in .then right after destroy. In my case I tried to create same DB after destriong old one in separate function (wrapped in Promise in order to chain) - and it didn'r work, no idea why